# R - Filter a specific variable based on other variables

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have the problem that I want to filter my variable Position(containing 5 atomic levels: Analyst, CEO, Analyst level II, Manger II, Ceo Level II) for age.

This means that I want to remove Analyst level II","Ceo level II","Manger level II" if their age is below 58 or keep them if their age is above 58. The other atomic levels (Analyst, CEO) shouldn't be affected by the age constraint. (example: analyst, age=50 should be kept)

```
library(tidyverse)
```

`Test<- tibble(Age=50:69,Position=rep(c("Analyst","Analyst Level II","Ceo level II", "Manager", "Manager level II"), times=4),Value=201:220)
exam32 <-Test %>%
  filter(!Position==c("Analyst level II","Ceo level II","Manager level II"), Age>58)
View(exam32)`

Hope you can help

Comment: Hello thank you for your response. I have made a tibble to make it reproducible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%in%` to match the string, and `&` specifying that both condition should be satisfied.

```
Test %>%
  filter(!(Position %in% c("Analyst level II",
                           "Ceo level II",
                           "Manager level II") & Age < 58)) 

# # A tibble: 17 x 3
#      Age Position         Value
#    <int> <chr>            <int>
#  1    50 Analyst            201
#  2    51 Analyst Level II   202
#  3    53 Manager            204
#  4    55 Analyst            206
#  5    56 Analyst Level II   207
#  6    58 Manager            209
#  7    59 Manager level II   210
#  8    60 Analyst            211
#  9    61 Analyst Level II   212
# 10    62 Ceo level II       213
# 11    63 Manager            214
# 12    64 Manager level II   215
# 13    65 Analyst            216
# 14    66 Analyst Level II   217
# 15    67 Ceo level II       218
# 16    68 Manager            219
# 17    69 Manager level II   220
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer that did it!